# Indeterminate checkbox in ExtJS

Tags: javascript, extjs, checkbox, tri-state-logic

Can we have indeterminate checkboxes in ExtJS as it's possible in native HTML? I mean something like:

[image: Different checkbox states]

All I could find are a couple of outdated extensions, and forum posts suggest that this isn't (yet) possible without subclassing the standard framework checkbox or creating a custom component.

Comment: `You can't make a checkbox indeterminate through HTML by design`. For Ext, there also is no way. You would have to subclass the standard framework, I'd guess six to ten lines own code are necessary for the UI; and then you would have to add indeterminateValue config option and return the correct value whenever the checkbox is set to indeterminate, which will be more of an issue because there are so many ways to retrieve the value of a checkbox.

Comment: There's an extension for ExtJS 2 I think, you can find it here http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?28096-2.x-Tri-state-checkbox-and-themed-checkbox-and-radio. If you're using a newer version of ExtJS you may want to take a look at it anyway so you can build one yourself

Answer (score 0):

Tri State Check boxes are discussed [here](http://extjs.com/forum/showthread.php?t=28096) . THe answer is for Ext **2.*** . 
This link was added
Tri State CHeck box is also [here](https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?98442)

A walk through of the plugin is on this private [website](http://www.jbruni.com.br/extjs-tristate/)